# Nested Matlab Property listener

Tags: matlab

The property postSet of MATLAB handle classes are very handy, however I would be happy to be able to trigger nested classes separately. A minimal example with two nested classes for illustration:

```
classdef parentClass < handle
    properties (SetObservable = true)
        childClass
    end

    methods
        function this = parentClass()
            this.childClass = childClass();
        end
    end 
end
```

and

```
classdef childClass < handle
    properties (SetObservable = true)
        value
    end

    methods
        function this = childClass()
            this.value = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

In the example script "runTest"

```
p = parentClass();

addlistener(p.childClass,'value','PostSet',@(o,e)disp('child value set'));
addlistener(p,'childClass','PostSet',@(o,e)disp('parent value set'));

p.childClass.value = 1;
```

The result is (as expected)

```
>> runTest
child value set
```

However, I am looking for an elegant way to detect the property change on both levels such that the result would be:

```
>> runTest
child value set
parent value set
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the fact that the `PostSet` event gets triggered by default even when the previous and current values are the same. In the constructor of `parentClass`, we add a listener to the `childClass`'s `PostSet` event, and the event handler only reassigns the `childClass` object:

```
classdef parentClass < handle
    properties (SetObservable = true)
        childClass
    end

    methods
        function this = parentClass()
            this.childClass = childClass();
            addlistener(this.childClass,'value','PostSet', @this.handlePropEvent);
        end
        function handlePropEvent(this, src, event)
            this.childClass = this.childClass;
        end

    end 
end
```

Note that you would want to be more careful implementing this so that the event listener gets adequately disposed of (and reassigned) if the `childClass` property is assigned a different object.

In practice, `childClass` should probably implement its own event type which gets triggered by all property changes you're interested in, and `parentClass` only listens to that event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe that your "in practice" suggestion is the way to go.